# ASP.NET MVC Identity Email/Username with Special Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

When registering an account through **Web API** with an email such as "xxx-yyy@gmail.com", Fiddler returns the follow error. *Note that email is used for username as well, so both fields are the same*. But it works when registering on MVC itself.

> ExceptionMessage=User Creation Failed - Identity Exception. Errors were:
>
> User name xx-yyy@gmail.com is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

**User Object**

```
 var newUser = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = user.Email,
            Email = user.Email
        };
```

**IdentifyConfig.cs**

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager) {
            RequireUniqueEmail = true,
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false

        };
```

I have tried commenting out *AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames* but it didn't work. By right setting it to false should allow special characters, in my case a hyphen(-).

**API Controller**

```
// POST: api/auth/register
    [ActionName("Register")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRegister(Auth user) {


        //dash issue is here. 

        var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(userContext);

        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var newUser = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = user.Email,
            Email = user.Email
        };

        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.PasswordHash);

        if (result.Succeeded) {
        ...
```

**Solution**

There is NO changes to *IdentityConfig.cs*. Only changes is to my API Controller.

```
  // POST: api/auth/register
        [ActionName("Register")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRegister(Auth user) {

//Changed to the following line
            ApplicationUserManager userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            var newUser = new ApplicationUser {
                UserName = user.Email,
                Email = user.Email
            };

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, user.PasswordHash);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are setting `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false` in `Create` method of `ApplicationUserManager`.
Inside the `PostRegister` action of your `ApiController` you are newing an instance of `ApplicationUserManager`. `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` is true by default.

You can change the Constructor of `ApplicationUserManager`

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store): base(store)
{
      UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
      {
           AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
           RequireUniqueEmail = true
      };
}
```

That way `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` is set to false when you new an instance of `ApplicationUserManger`.

**Note:**
Its better to get the `ApplicationUserManager` from `OwinContext` same as done in `AccountController` of default MVC5 template or use Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I followed what you recommended in your note. I've edited my question to reflect the working solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

That's because all your config is in `ApplicationUserManager`, which you aren't using in your Web Api action. Instead, you're newing up plain-old `UserManager`, which will then use the defaults for all the validation and such.