# How To Change Password Validation in ASP.Net MVC Identity 2 - Part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-identity

Before anyone suggests that this is the same question as the link below:

[How To Change Password Validation in ASP.Net MVC Identity 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796454/how-to-change-password-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-identity-2)

I would like to assure people that it is more of a continuation of this question.

I went into the IdentityConfig.cs as the first answer to the above link suggested and changed all the options as follows:

```
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 2,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
```

Next, as the second answer suggested I also went into the AccountViewModels.cs class and changed the 2 places there which sets the minimum length of the password. I again set it from 6 to 2 (in both places it appears within the file.

```
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
```

I then went ahead and done a search for the phrase "must be at least" throughout the entire solution. I found one other class: ManageViewModels.cs and again in the two places this appeared I altered the minimum length setting it from 6 to 2 in both places, just as above.

I am trying to setup some default roles and a super user in the Startup.cs (Personally I would not do it this way, but I am just following an article on securing my CMS). One of the first steps is this.

In my Startup.cs I have the following simple code:

```
        //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                        
        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.UserName = "super";
        user.Email = "super@krypton.com";
        string userPWD = "1234";
        IdentityResult chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

        //Add default User to Role Admin
        if (chkUser.Succeeded)
        {
            IdentityResult result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
        }
```

It should work. But when I break on it, and hover over the chkUser variable, I find that I am getting an error saying "The Password must be at least 6 characters long.".

Even after changing all the validation logic to say it should be 2 characters.

So my question is: Is there another location where yet more validation logic is done? Also, is there a single place where I can extract all this validation logic to (if so, can someone perhaps suggest a link or two to such a resource or provide a suggestion on how to approach it).

Comment: you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260640/asp-net-mvc-identity-email-username-with-special-characters/37261830). Its about UserValidator but I think you are facing the same issue.

Comment: @tmg - thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the link and tried to implement it as suggested. The blocker I am facing is that it requires me to make the Startup.cs inherit from controller in order to give me the ability to add the GetOwinContext properties and inject them. The problem I face is that it is the Startup.cs file. It feels wrong, like adding a controller to the global.asax or something. Perhaps I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The true and only link you can get is to the source code of `PasswordValidator`. Here you go: http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/PasswordValidator.cs

Only it is really doing what it is supposed to do. I can only guess that you assigning `PasswordValidator` to the wrong instance of `UserManager` and settings that you set are not used.

What you can do is to copy the source code for `PasswordValidator`, paste it into your codebase and step-through in debug mode, figuring out where the requirement is coming from.

Comment: From the code recommended (which may change by the time others read this in the future), I can see there is a required length property and a subsequent check. I also looked into the referenced resource file, I don't see any potential for a bug of any kind. However, I will do as you suggest and download and step through it to see the values as they are passed along. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers The linked codebase is for MVC5. Next version of Identity for ASP.Net Core is hosted on GitHub. And as far as I understand development on Identity v2.x is pretty much frozen. So don't worry about changed codebase -)